# Регулярное выражение по HTML

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть такой HTML-код:

```
<div id="community_header" class="wcommunity_header">  
  <a class="wcommunity_header_avatar" href="https://vk.com/durov" target="_blank"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c629231/v629231001/c543/FfB--bOEVOY.jpg"></a>  
  <div class="wcommunity_name"><a class="wcommunity_name_link" href="https://vk.com/durov" target="_blank">Павел Дуров</a></div>  
  <div class="wcommunity_status">道德經</div>  
</div>
```

Я составил для этого кода регулярное выражение:

```
\<div\ id\=\"community\_header\"\ class\=\"wcommunity\_header\"\>\<a.+\<\/a\>\<div.+\<\/div\>\<div.+\<\/div\>\<\/div\>
```

Но оно, почему-то, пишет, что нет совпадений. Кто знает в чём дело?

Comment: Потому что не нужно парсить HTML-код регулярками

Comment: @andreymal, а как мне можно через PHP редактировать это по другому?

Comment: Взять любой существующий html-парсер, благо таких под php (и под другие языки тоже) должно быть навалом

Comment: @andreymal, не могли бы вы ссылку кинуть? Я в PHP новичок, пока ещё не дошёл до этого в обучении

Comment: [Да хоть тот же DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: @andreymal, мда, час от часу не легче. Будем разбираться :)

Comment: Вы не написали, что нужно найти в строке HTML.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, мне нужно весь этот код удалить из общего

Comment: Т.е. из HTML удалить все `div` c `id="community_header"` и `class="wcommunity_header"`? Я спрашиваю, т.к. для XPath это имеет значение.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, да

Comment: См. [этот код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f2455f21d6b0fc90de9e47564d87d81760dbc61).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, воу, неплохо. Дайте ответом и я его приму :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, а зачем добавлять в "HTML код" чёрточку? Разве вы добавляете её, когда пишите "хороший код" или что-то в этом роде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для манипуляций с HTML лучше пользоваться HTML-парсером. Вот пример использования PHP [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) для удаления определенных тегов вместе с их содержимым:

```
$html = <<<DATA
<body>
<h1>Start</h1>
<div id="community_header" class="wcommunity_header">  
  <a class="wcommunity_header_avatar" href="https://vk.com/durov" target="_blank"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c629231/v629231001/c543/FfB--bOEVOY.jpg"></a>  
  <div class="wcommunity_name"><a class="wcommunity_name_link" href="https://vk.com/durov" target="_blank">Павел Дуров</a></div>  
  <div class="wcommunity_status">道德經</div>  
</div>
<img src="newimg.gif">
</body>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); // Инициализация DOMDocument
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); // Заполнение структуры данными

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom); // Инициализация DOMXPath нашими данными
$divs = $xpath->query('//div[@id="community_header" and @class="wcommunity_header"]'); // Запрос XPath

foreach ($divs as $div) {
    $div->parentNode->removeChild($div); // Удаление найденных элементов
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

См. [демо этого кода](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f2455f21d6b0fc90de9e47564d87d81760dbc61).

Запрос XPath означает:

- `//div` - найди все `div`, в которых
- `[@id="community_header" - атрибут`id`равен`community_header`
- `and` - а также
- `@class="wcommunity_header"]` - атрибут `class` равен `wcommunity_header`.

Comment: Спасибочка вам :3

Comment: Добавил комментарии с объяснением XPath.

Answer (score 2):

Не работает из-за того, что вот в этом месте

```
\<div\ id\=\"community\_header\"\ class\=\"wcommunity\_header\"\>\<
                                                               ^^^^
```

как и в других, потерялись перевод строки и пробельные символы.

Следующая ошибка в жадном захвате:

```
<div.+\<\/div\>
```

Скорее всего эта конструкция сожрёт всё до конца, так что так делать не надо.

Как можно было бы попробовать:

1. Все пробелы заменять на `\s+` или `\s*`.
2. Найти начало первого `div`а.

   ```
   <div\s+id="community_header"\s+class="wcommunity_header">
   ```
3. Промотать в нём всё, что не связано с `div`ами

   ```
   (?!</?div\b)[\s\S]
   ```

   или является одноуровневым `div`ом без лишней вложенности:

   ```
   <div(\s+[^>]*)?>((?!</?div\b)[\s\S])*</div>
   ```

   получается

   ```
   ((?!</?div\b)[\s\S]|<div(\s+[^>]*)?>((?!</?div\b)[\s\S])*</div>)*
   ```
4. Взять закрывывающий тег `div`а:

   ```
   </div>
   ```

Целиком получается такая штука:

```
<div\s+id="community_header"\s+class="wcommunity_header">((?!</?div\b)[\s\S]|<div(\s+[^>]*)?>((?!</?div\b)[\s\S])*</div>)*</div>
```

Чего-то, что прямо обязательно требовало бы экранирования нет. В php можно использовать любые ограничители для регулярных выражений, например `#`. В случае js надо экранировать слеши `/` и получится

```
<div\s+id="community_header"\s+class="wcommunity_header">((?!<\/?div\b)[\s\S]|<div(\s+[^>]*)?>((?!<\/?div\b)[\s\S])*<\/div>)*<\/div>
```

Попробуем (нужен браузер с поддержкой ES6):

```js
var pattern = /<div\s+id="community_header"\s+class="wcommunity_header">((?!<\/?div\b)[\s\S]|<div(\s+[^>]*)?>((?!<\/?div\b)[\s\S])*<\/div>)*<\/div>/ig;

console.log(`
    <div> Just a div </div>
    <div id="community_header" class="wcommunity_header">  
      <a class="wcommunity_header_avatar" href="https://vk.com/durov" target="_blank"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c629231/v629231001/c543/FfB--bOEVOY.jpg"></a>  
      <div class="wcommunity_name"><a class="wcommunity_name_link" href="https://vk.com/durov" target="_blank">Павел Дуров</a></div>  
      <div class="wcommunity_status">道德經</div>  
    </div>
    <div>  <!-- должен остаться -->
      <a class="wcommunity_header_avatar" href="https://vk.com/durov" target="_blank"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c629231/v629231001/c543/FfB--bOEVOY.jpg"></a>  
      <div class="wcommunity_name"><a class="wcommunity_name_link" href="https://vk.com/durov" target="_blank">Павел Дуров</a></div>  
      <div class="wcommunity_status">道德經</div>  
    </div>
    <div id="community_header" class="wcommunity_header">  
      <a class="wcommunity_header_avatar" href="https://vk.com/durov" target="_blank"><img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c629231/v629231001/c543/FfB--bOEVOY.jpg"></a>  
      <div class="wcommunity_name"><a class="wcommunity_name_link" href="https://vk.com/durov" target="_blank">Павел Дуров</a></div>  
      <div class="wcommunity_status">道德經</div>  
    </div>
`.replace(pattern, ""));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100%; }
```

Но вообще имеет смысл воспользоваться нормальным html-парсером.

Comment: У меня ничего не убралось...

Comment: Пардон, убралось :)

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже попарсил)